# Finding non-expiring keys in Redis

Tags: redis

In my setup, the `info` command shows me the following:

```
[keys] => 1128
[expires] => 1125
```

I'd like to find those 3 keys without an expiration date. I've already checked the docs to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't help but wonder if everybody else that arrived here did so because a `getset` command nuked the TTL they had on a key. That's not something that's documented and it's something that happens. `getset` is slated for deprecation, but this bit us hard.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Modified from a site that I can't find now.

```
redis-cli keys  "*" | while read LINE ; do TTL=`redis-cli ttl "$LINE"`; if [ $TTL -eq  -1 ]; then echo "$LINE"; fi; done;
```

edit: Note, this is a blocking call.

Comment: TTL is `-1` for no expiration keys (instead of `3600`).

Comment: That is an excellent point, thanks for pointing it out. Edited the answer and upvoting your comment.

Comment: I get an error when I try this on a remote redis host. I connect to the remote host and then from the prompt I run: `keys  "*" | while read LINE ; do TTL=`redis-cli ttl $LINE`; if [ $TTL -eq  -1 ]; then echo "$LINE"; fi; done;` but I get an "invalid arguments" error

Comment: Please make sure to double-quote `$TTL`. If one of the keys has a space, bash will give the `bash: [: too many arguments` error. Also, I had to use `==` over `-eq` due to this error: `bash: [: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'ttl' command: integer expression expected`.

Comment: well, maybe it's this [link](http://web.performancerasta.com/deleting-all-non-expiring-keys-in-a-redis-sever-from-command-line/)

Comment: This will launch a `redis-cli` process and reconnect to redis for every single key in the store. That may be millions or even billions. Is there not a better way to do this with a single connection?

Comment: if you're doing this on production, make sure to take a dump and runs this command. Running keys will hamper the performance significantly

Comment: The [Redis KEYS command](https://redis.io/commands/KEYS) can stop Redis from processing requests. Using SCAN will take only about 10% engine CPU depending on your architecture.

Answer (score 62):

@Waynn Lue's answer runs but uses the Redis KEYS command which [Redis warns about](https://redis.io/commands/KEYS):

> Warning: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases.

Redis documentation recommends using SCAN.

```
redis-cli --scan | while read LINE ; do TTL=`redis-cli ttl "$LINE"`; if [ $TTL -eq  -1 ]; then echo "$LINE"; fi; done;
```

If you want to scan for a specific key pattern, use:

```
 redis-cli --scan --pattern "something*"
```

Comment: When I try your first example, I get the error "Invalid argument(s): Closing quote must be followed by a space or nothing at all" and I can't seem to get around it. I'm new to redis, and using Redis InSight Workbench.

Answer (score 4):

In case somebody is getting bad arguments or wrong number of arguments error,
put double quotes around $LINE.

So,it would be

```
redis-cli keys  "*" | while read LINE ; do TTL=`redis-cli ttl "$LINE"`; if [ $TTL -eq  -1 ]; then echo "$LINE"; fi; done;
```

This happens when there are spaces in the key.

Comment: This is an improvement (bug fix) upon the existing answer and as such should be an edit of that answer.

Answer (score 4):

To me the accepted answer appears unusable for a medium-sized dataset, as it will run a `redis-cli` command for each and every key.

Instead I used this lua script to filter the keys inside the redis server:

```lua
local show_persistent = ARGV[1] ~= "expiring"

local keys = {}
for i, name in ipairs(redis.call("keys", "*")) do
    local persistent = redis.call("pttl", name) < 0
    if persistent == show_persistent then
        table.insert(keys, name)
    end
end

return keys
```

This can be called as

```sh
$ redis-cli --eval show-persistent-keys.lua
```

to get all keys without an expiration time. It also can be called as

```sh
$ redis-cli --eval show-persistent-keys.lua , expiring
```

to find the opposite key set of all keys with an expiration time set.

On the downside this may block for too long (appears fine for 1 M keys). I'd use scan instead but I happen to have to run this against a legacy Redis at version 2.6, which does not have `scan` available.

Comment: I was looking for something to show me keys with a TTL and this worked great!

Answer (score 3):

I needed to extract non-expiring keys from bigger (40GB) dataset, so using `keys` command was not suitable for me. So in case someone is looking for offline/non-blocking solution, you can use https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools for extraction of non-expiring keys from redis rdb dump.

You can just install libraries via pip:

`pip install rdbtools python-lzf`

Then create simple parser which extracts keys and values which has expiration set to None:

```
from rdbtools import RdbParser, RdbCallback
from rdbtools.encodehelpers import bytes_to_unicode

class ParserCallback(RdbCallback):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ParserCallback, self).__init__(string_escape=None)

    def encode_key(self, key):
        return bytes_to_unicode(key, self._escape, skip_printable=True)

    def encode_value(self, val):
        return bytes_to_unicode(val, self._escape)

    def set(self, key, value, expiry, info):
        if expiry is None:
            print('%s = %s' % (self.encode_key(key), self.encode_value(value)))


callback = ParserCallback()
parser = RdbParser(callback)
parser.parse('/path/to/dump.rdb')
```

Comment: Nice! This is definitely the best answer in 2021 (assuming you have access to the RDB files, which isn't the case for hosted services).

Comment: @aron23 It doesn't seem to be printing sets in the output, only keys of type strings

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to accomplish the same at work, where I need to find keys without TTL set and then delete them.

This script is written in Java, I ran it using my IDE.

1. Check the port number is correct (it needs to be the same port number opened when access to the cluster is established)
2. Check that the Redis key name that you want to match on is correct

```java
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig;
import redis.clients.jedis.params.ScanParams;

class RemoveRedisKeysWithoutTtl {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JedisPool jedisPool = new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), "localhost", 6379);

    try (Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource()) {
      // call the method to remove keys with no TTL set
      removeKeysWithNoTTL(jedis);

      System.out.println("Keys with no TTL removed successfully.");
    }

    // close the connection
    jedisPool.close();
  }

  public static void removeKeysWithNoTTL(Jedis jedis) {
    // update the pattern to match on your key
    ScanParams scanParams = new ScanParams().match("*");

    // start at the beginning of the cursor, so value is 0
    String cursor = ScanParams.SCAN_POINTER_START;

    do {
      var scanResult = jedis.scan(cursor, scanParams);
      var keys = scanResult.getResult();

      // iterate through keys
      for (String key : keys) {
        // check if TTL is -1 (no expiration) or -2 (key does not exist)
        if (jedis.ttl(key) == -1 || jedis.ttl(key) == -2) {
          // Delete the key
          System.out.println("Deleting key " + key);
          jedis.del(key);
        }
      }

      // get the next cursor
      cursor = scanResult.getCursor();
    } while (!cursor.equals(ScanParams.SCAN_POINTER_START));
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
import redis

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("-i", '--host', type=str, default="127.0.0.1", help="redis host", required=False)
p.add_argument("-p", '--port', type=int, default=6379, help="redis port", required=False)
p.add_argument("-n", '--db', type=int, default=0, help="redis database", required=False)

args = p.parse_args()

r = redis.Redis(host=args.host, port=args.port, db=args.db)

try:
    keys = r.keys()

    for key in keys:
        if r.ttl(key) < 0:
            print(key)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```