# How to find redis keys by TTL

Tags: linux, redis, redis-cli

I want to find any/all redis keys with TTL is `-1`. That's every key that is not set to expire. I've tried a couple GUI clients and none of them seem to off this functionality.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817951/finding-non-expiring-keys-in-redis) which appears to offer a way to do it from the command line. But I get "invalid argument" errors when I try it locally or on my remote redis host.

LOCAL

`` redis-cli keys  "*" | while read LINE ; do TTL=`redis-cli ttl $LINE`; if [ $TTL -eq  -1 ]; then echo "$LINE"; fi; done; ``

REMOTE

`` $redis-cli -h ... -p ... -a
redis>> keys  "*" | while read LINE ; do TTL=`redis-cli ttl $LINE`; if [ $TTL -eq  -1 ]; then echo "$LINE"; fi; done; ``

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The remote invocation will not work since you're pasting *bash* script into the prompt of redis-cli.

Also, try to use this on the conditional expressions: `[[ $TTL -eq  -1 ]]`

(two brackets instead).

Comment: No the local script also doesn't work. It's a similar error about arguments

Comment: Maybe the local doesn't work because of 0 results on my local? I don't know bash well enough to predict how it would handle that